# Update XML file after changing it content using JTree

Tags: java, xml, swing, jtree, jfilechooser

I am trying to update the content of the XML file after changing some parameters using `JTree`. The new value is given by the user, not pre-defined. The values are supposed to be changed as an example 7.5. The file does not only have these names, it's a large XML file.

```xml
<config>
<module name="JDEQSim" >
<param name="carSize" value="7.5" />
<param name="endTime" value="undefined" />
<param name="flowCapacityFactor" value="1.0" />
<param name="gapTravelSpeed" value="15.0" />
<param name="minimumInFlowCapacity" value="1800.0" />
<param name="squeezeTime" value="1800.0" />
<param name="storageCapacityFactor" value="1.0" />
</module>
...
</config>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how can the content of the JTree choosen by the user stay saved for the next use of the Program.

Comment: Save it to a file. There are many questions here that deal with that. Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: no its a project that am workin on.